# Verify all JS and CSS has been minified

Tags: javascript, php, curl, minify, simple-html-dom

I want to be able to load in a list of sites and verify that all CSS and JS has been minified. I would prefer to use PHP to do this, but I'm at a bit of a loss.

I've written a basic script that uses simpleHtmlDom to get the links for all the script tags in the DOM, but after that I'm not exactly sure how to verify it's been minified other then regex for \n.

I've also entertained the thought that simpleHtmlDom is not catching all of the scripts such as those loaded in on other scripts and not exactly in the DOM, for this I was going to use CURL, but I'm not exactly sure how to proceed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it important that you check the dynamically-loaded scripts or css in PHP? Because if you have control of the JS/CSS files that get pushed to the server, you can use a task runner like grunt to minify all your js and css automatically for you before the files get sent to server, or committed to the repo.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's terribly important, no. But say I wanted to verify that the task runners such as grunt are properly minifying the files. An added layer of QA if you will.

Comment: For checking if minified how about you minify them yourself and check the sizes. For scripts loaded in other scripts you're going to need a javascript or full-browser solution.

Comment: If you have a file called "script.js", and you run it through grunt to minify it, you can also have grunt rename the file for you to "script.min.js", this gives you a specific file to check for in PHP, and you can check the sizes (compared to the original) and possibly the date modified. But I find that grunt is so reliable that it will minify without an issue and taking that extra step to verify is not necessary. If you are pushing a minified file to the server, then there is no reason to check for minification every time that file is served.